# I need to create a SQLite table

Tags: sql, sqlite

I need to be able to enter duplicate entries in Table B, with different foreign keys (Table B references Table A's key).  Like this:

```
Table A:
Record with key of 11
Record with key of 22

Table B:
Record referring to Table A record 11, with a field marked unique: value 101
Record referring to Table A record 22, with a field marked unique: value 101  <--- violates the unique key
```

This is what I have tried, but didn't work:

```
CREATE TABLE Readings (
    SITE_ID TEXT REFERENCES SiteData
    , LOOP_NBR TEXT
    , LOOP_CLOSED BINARY
    , SEQ INTEGER
    , STA TEXT UNIQUE
    , BS TEXT
    , FS TEXT
    , HI TEXT
    , DESC TEXT
 )  

INSERT INTO Readings (SITE_ID, SEQ) VALUES (' + databaseKey + ', 0)
```

Anybody know how to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
CREATE TABLE Readings (
    SITE_ID TEXT UNIQUE REFERENCES SiteData 
    , LOOP_NBR TEXT
    , LOOP_CLOSED BINARY
    , SEQ INTEGER
    , STA TEXT UNIQUE
    , BS TEXT
    , FS TEXT
    , HI TEXT
    , DESC TEXT
 )
```

Adding UNIQUE to the foreign key will refuse only rows with same SITE_ID and STA

Comment: Uh... no it won't. Adding UNIQUE to the foreign key means that you can't have duplicate values within that column. The UNIQUE constraint is applied only to that column.

Comment: Sorry, but that didn't do it either... shouldn't there be a way to make the records in Table B separate and distinct from any records with different keys from Table A?

Comment: I suppose, if worse came to worse, I could always remove the constraint and do a SELECT to see if it is a duplicate, right?

Answer (score 1):

If table B has a unique constraint on a column, then if you want to enter a duplicate value into that column, you have to remove the unique constraint.

**Edit:** In other words, remove the word `UNIQUE` from your table creation code. I assume that "a field marked unique" is referring to the `STA` column, because that's the only unique column you have in there.

**Edit the second:** According to your comments below, you want to put a constraint on unique combinations of the `SITE_ID` and `STA` fields. You'd change your SQL query to be:

```
CREATE TABLE Readings (
    SITE_ID TEXT REFERENCES SiteData,
    LOOP_NBR TEXT,
    LOOP_CLOSED BINARY,
    SEQ INTEGER,
    STA TEXT, 
    BS TEXT,
    FS TEXT,
    HI TEXT,
    DESC TEXT,
    CONSTRAINT UNIQUE (SITE_ID, STA)
 )
```

Comment: Yes, it's the STA column.  However, if I remove the UNIQUE constraint, how do I not allow duplicates within the same SITE_ID?

Comment: You add a [table constraint](http://www.sqlite.org/syntaxdiagrams.html#table-constraint), something like "CONSTRAINT UNIQUE (SITE_ID, STA)"

Comment: @Spokane-Dude: Did you see my second edit here? The other answer that you accepted is wrong (and you even said so in your comment).